# Is there a way to use iOS Size Classes without interface builder(programatically)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have been using Interface Builder with the new xcode 6 and using the Size Classes for interface design. For past projects I just code all the interface and the constraints. This works great since my team can just pull/push/merge the code easily.

Is there a way to continue just using only code and use Size Classes?

I have found several references to Size Classes, but they all mention only the use with Interface Builder:

- http://carpeaqua.com/2014/06/14/thinking-in-terms-of-ios-8-size-classes/
- http://mathewsanders.com/designing-adaptive-layouts-for-iphone-6-plus

Edit:

In particular, how to set constraints for different Size Classes by code

Comment: Why not? The APIs let you deal with size classes (trait collections). What specific question do you have?

Comment: I was a bit confused about this too. If you look for "Size Class" in the documentation, the only thing that pops up is Interface Builder. Same with Size Classes/Adaptive Layout and constraints - multiple help articles but all about IB. I also went looking in vain for a class reference a few weeks ago. A bit hard to find if you don't know to look for `traitCollection` instead. There is no link to `UIUserInterfaceSizeClass` except from within the `UITraitCollection` class reference. "Size Classes" aren't actually "classes" at all, but a typedef, so the name is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

All IB is doing here is implementing `traitCollectionDidChange:`. It isn't doing anything you can't do in code by switching on the `traitCollection` and its `horizontalSizeClass` and `verticalSizeClass`, and in fact code might be clearer (and more flexible).

Comment: IB gives you an advantage of supporting both iOS7 and iOS8. UITraitCollection, on the other hand, is available for iOS8 only. You'll have to write some additional code to support both.